# How to switch data from a Table A to Table B when there is no query running on Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 Table A, B, which have the same columns. Table B is Used for Tableau Reports. Table A is a temporary Table which has new Data from source System.
How to switch the Data from Table A to Table B when there is no Query running on Table B?
i need to do that to avoid downtime on Table B and make sure that Table B is always available for Users
Thankyou very much!

Comment: "no Query running on table?" did you meant you could not run query on table

Comment: What do you mean about "no Query running on Table A"?

Comment: I think you would do this using views or synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is something you cannot really do with straightforward methods since any RDBMS will take care of this functionality by itself. The only thing you *can* do is put your insert statements in a `transaction` block to make sure that the resulting table B will never be seen(=queried) in an "unready" (=half finished) state.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly this is the scenario;

> 1 You load data into **TableA** and then the endusers use **TableB**
>
> 2 You want to switch data into **TableB** from **TableA** without downtime

This should solve your problem:

```
truncate table [dbo].[TableB]           alter table [dbo].[TableA]      switch to   [dbo].[TableB]
```

This script executes within miliseconds and should be enough for your requirements. One notice though is that your **TableA** and **TableB** has to be completely the same. Same Index, same columns etc.

Comment: The statements must be run in a transaction else users could use the empty `TableB` between statements and those queries would block the `SWITCH`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes true- But he writes how it can be done when there is no query at all. So i guess the endusers are not able to use the system when he wants to switch.

Comment: The question also specifies `TableB` is always available to users and @phalondon has not answered the question from the comment as to what is intended. An explict transaction here will address both cases since the `TRUNCATE` to wait until current queries finish and no new queries will start until the `COMMIT` of both `TRUNCATE` and `SWITCH`.